# How to prove $E(Y\mid E(X))=E(Y)$?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, statistical-inference

To prove the question what I did:
for an unknown random variable $U$
$$E(Y\mid E(X))=E(E(U\mid X)\mid E(X))=E(E(U\mid E(X))\mid X),$$
because $E(X)$ is function of X. So, finally
$$E(Y\mid E(X))=E(U\mid E(X))=E(Y).$$
The problems are here:
I have to assume $Y=E(U\mid X)$ and $Y=U\mid E(X),$ which may be possible if there is a linear function such that $U=f(X).$
Is my idea right? If not then do you have any ideas or recommendations? And how do I find the variable $U$ so that it has a well defined relation with $X$ and $Y$.

The above question arises from a regression model can be described in a different way. Suppose, I have a formula based on E(X) but I can only use E(Y). However, I know there is a linear relationship between Y and X such that I can formulate a regression model. For example for a regression model we have
$$Y=\alpha + \beta X + \text{error},$$ therefore, $$E(Y\mid X)=\alpha+\beta X.$$ So, We can have
$$E(Y\mid E(X))=\alpha+\beta E(X),$$ for a value $E(X).$ My question is, since I can not use $E(X)$, then what is the corresponding value of $E(Y)$ should I use instead of $E(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

$E(X)$ is just some number, or constant function if you like. The $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ generated by this constant function is trivial. Hence, $E(Y \mid E(X)) = E(Y \mid \mathcal{F}) = E(Y)$.

See this question: [Conditional Expectation: What happens if you take conditional expectation on trivial sigma field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248567/conditional-expectation-what-happens-if-you-take-conditional-expectation-on-tri)

Comment: You are right. Actually I was thinking something else. I edited my questions and added more information. Thank you so much.