# Writing out the proof for Conditional Expectation on trivial sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Let us have $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$

I intuitively understand that with the information available $\Omega$, the best guess of $X$ is $E(X)$.

However, I want to write out the proof and I follow one of the answer from
[Conditional Expectation: What happens if you take conditional expectation on trivial sigma field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248567/conditional-expectation-what-happens-if-you-take-conditional-expectation-on-tri)

The answer:

$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]1_A] = E[X1_A] \quad \forall\ A \in \mathcal{F}$$

By substituting $A=\Omega$, I reduce both sides to $E[X]$ and I think I am doing something wrong.

My process:

$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]1_\Omega] = E[E[X|\Omega]] = E[X] \tag1$$

$$ E[X1_A] = E[X1_\Omega] = E[X] \tag2$$

As if $X \not\in \Omega$, $E[X] = E[0] = 0$.

So I am just stupidly stuck here and could not show that $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = E[X]$.

One thing that just strike me as I type this answer is that is $E[X1_\Omega] = E[X|\Omega]= E[X|\mathcal{F}]$? Or am I just being stupid again?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $E[X|\mathcal F]=EX$ you have to show two things:

1. $EX $ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F$
2. $E[1_A (E[X|\mathcal F])]=E(EX)1_A$ for all $A \in \mathcal F$.

The first one  follows from the fact that $EX$ is a constant, hence measurable w.r.t any $\sigma-$algebra.

To prove the second one you only have to  apply the  definition conditional expectation for the left hand side. This side becoms $E[X1_A]$. Now equality follows by pulling out $EX$ from right hand side and  considering the cases $A=\emptyset$ and $A=\Omega$. Both sides are $0$ in first case and $EX$ in the second case.